# Autocomplete angular js from php array with json and $http

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, angularjs

I have to made something like this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9zsrvLLfH8hKGwmIeZVv?p=preview) I found, an autocomplete, but I have to use a php array, using `$http`.

If I put an alert to see my array, works fine, but I don't have any idea of what I have to do to make this filter in angularjs :(

My $http:

```
/*CONNESSIONE HTTP -------------------------------------- */  
$scope.connessione = function (){
    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://www.fattura.local/contatti.php'}).

    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert(data);        
    }).

    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("errore.");
    });   };    }]);
```

My Php array:

```
<?php

$contatti = array('Mario Rossi, Via Cippina,1 - 10100 Torino','Giacomo Puccini, Via Cippella, 2 10100 Torino','Giuseppe Verdi, Via Aida, 14 10100 Torino','Nicolò Paganini, Via NonRipetibile, 33 10023 Chieri');
echo json_encode($contatti);
```

Comment: Your exemple use the typeahead directive http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead

Comment: I donk know how, but I solved it in this way:

 <textarea ng-model="selected" ng-click="connessione()"
    typeahead="contatti for contatti in contatti | filter:$viewValue"> <!-- $viewValue =  "is the value that is entered by a user" google dixit-->
    </textarea>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good solution is [datalist](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp) html tag. It has disadvantage of not being supported in safari and IE9 and older. But it is very clean HTML solution.

```
<input list="data" />
<datalist id="data">
    <option value="data1"></option>
    <option value="data2"></option>
    <option value="data3"></option>
    <option value="data4"></option>
    <option value="data5"></option>
</datalist>
```